# Internal search doesn't work after configuring solr

Tags: content-search, solr

The internal search stopped working. It was working fine until I configured Solr.

The changes I made are :

Disable all Lucene configs except the DefaultIndexConfiguration.config and enabled all Solr configs.

In the Solr DefaultIndexConfiguration.config, I have included some templates & fields in the respective nodes &

this is set to true - `<indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>`

[image]

There are no exceptions logged and I've checked Search.log, Crawling.log and the regular log.txt

Also, when I try to rebuild indexes in the Developer tab, it shows none.

Using Sitecore 8.0 Update 5

Comment: did you login on solr interface ? can you see there solr core?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber What is solr core. I can log into the solr interface and see all the custom cores I have created. There are no errors displayed there.

Comment: do you see master_index core into solr?

Comment: Yes, I see sitecore_master_index & Sitecore_core_index

Comment: did you rebuild all indexes?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber Yes. Rebuilt all the indexes.

Comment: Do you see any errors in any of Sitecore logs? You can also try capturing failing Solr requests using Fiddler.

Comment: In solr, look at the master_index, are there any documents listed in there? If so how many?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check configuration with Sitecore Role Checker Tool: https://github.com/reyrahadian/Sitecore-Server-Role-Checker

If you use SOLR all Lucene files should be disabled and when you use Lucene you should disable all SORL configuration files. You shouldn't use SORL & Lucene configuration files in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

When I first configured Solr, I disabled all Lucene configs except `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`

Now, I enabled `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Indexes.Sharded.Master.config` and its working fine now.

Comment: All Lucene files need to be disabled including Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config